# Why does a laserbeam bent downwards when shined through a solution of salt?

Tags: electromagnetism

When you have a aquarium with salt on the bottom and add water to it the salt will solute in water, but most of it will initially probably stay more or less down. Now is you shine a laserbeam through one of the walls from outside into the aquarium it, the beam will not travel straight but will bent a little towards the bottom. The reason for that is that there the density of the solution is the greatest and the light is transmitted less fast.
But why should a beam 'wants' to go to the densiest solution while it go straight having a higher speed?

Comment: You are describing refraction in a medium whose refractive index is varying continuously.

Answer (score 1):

If the light would travel straight, it would “tear apart”. The laser consists of wavefronts which are mostly flat surfaces if it has not been focused (large Rayleigh length). The wavefront of the laser has different speeds of light in different heights. This means that the lower part of the wavefront is slowed down more. In order to keep the wavefront intact and *perpendicular to the direction of propagation*, the beam has to bend down.

It is kind of like a car where you apply the brake on one side only, it will also move to one side.

The curvature of the light is not the salt itself, it is the gradient of the salt distribution in the water. I would think that if you stir the aquarium well enough, the laser should go straight. Once the more saturated water sinks to the bottom, there will be curvature again.